# Objective-C Authentication

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, cocoa, post

I am currently writing an iPhone application that will push a username and password to a website to retrieve the HTML source code of the page which loads.  I include login information in `NSString *post`.

When I `NSLog` the `_responseData` instance variable in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method, the console prints a long series of eight digit hexadecimal numbers which I assume are some type of address or encrypted HTML (3c21444f 43545950 45206874 6d6c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f5733...).

What should I do to convert/decrypt the addresses into HTML code or otherwise retrieve the HTML code of the webpage which loads?

My ViewController conforms to the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol and includes the following code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData *_responseData;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
    // so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
    // Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
    // also serves to clear it
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Received response");
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
    NSLog(@"Received data");
    [_responseData appendData:data];
}
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
              willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    // Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
    //NSString *html=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://grades.bsd405.org/Pinnacle/Gradebook/InternetViewer/GradeSummary.aspx?&EnrollmentId=770595&TermId=127463&ReportType=0&StudentId=114040"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Finished loading");

    //PRINT HTML:
    NSLog(@"Data: %@",_responseData);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // The request has failed for some reason!
    // Check the error var
    NSLog(@"Failed to load");
}

- (IBAction)goPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *post =     @"__LASTFOCUS&__EVENTTARGET&__EVENTARGUMENT&__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUJNTkxNzI3MDIzD2QWAmYPZBYCA
    gMPZBYGAgEPZBYCAgkPZBYCAgEPZBYIAgMPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZAIFDxYCHwBoZAIHDxYCHwBoZAIJDxYCHgVzdH
    lsZQUjdmVydGljYWwtYWxpZ246bWlkZGxlO2Rpc3BsYXk6bm9uZTtkAgMPDxYCHwBoZGQCBQ9kFghmD2QWAgINDxY
    CHgVjbGFzcwUQc2luZ2xlU2Nob29sTGlzdBYCAgEPZBYCAgEPEGQPFgFmFgEQBQ5EZWZhdWx0IERvbWFpbgUIUGlu
    bmFjbGVnZGQCAg9kFgICEw9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQCBw8PFgIeBFRleHQFIFBpbm5hY2xlIEdyYWRlIDIwM
    TIgV2ludGVyIEJyZWFrZGQCCA8PFgIfAwU3Q29weXJpZ2h0IChjKSAyMDEzIEdsb2JhbFNjaG9sYXIuICBBbGwgcm
    lnaHRzIHJlc2VydmVkLmRkZP/l6irI9peZfyqpKjk3fwLuEbos&__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWBgKjnbqUCQLnksmg
    AQKTpbWbDgLB5+KIBAL4xb20BAK20ZqiCel6sQLBsF1W3XHOxpgq+tJj+Rx2&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Use
        rname=TESTUSERNAME&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Password=TESTPASSWORD&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolde

    r$lstDomains=Pinnacle&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$LogonButton=Sign 
    in&PageUniqueId=2dacba26-

    bb0d-412f-b06a-e02caf039c4b";

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://grades.bsd405.org/Pinnacle/Gradebook/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPinnacle%2fGradebook%2fDefault.aspx"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSLog` of your `NSData` displays the object's `description`, which a hexadecimal string of the underlying binary data:

```
3c21444f 43545950 45206874 6d6c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f5733 ...
```

Translates to a string of

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3 ...
```

To get the `NSString` from the `NSData`, you do:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```